# The deletion FAQ item should reflect site policy

Tags: discussion, site-faq

[The FAQ item on deletion](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) claims the following about deleting answers:

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are …
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

The list should include *anecdotal/unreferenced answers*, too. (I got linked here after an answer of mine was deleted as anecdotal.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the network-wide FAQ, we can't change that part of the FAQ for just this site. We moderators can only change the first section of the FAQ.

We should link users to an appropriate meta post, not the FAQ in this case to avoid confusion.

Comment: For the record, that appropriate meta post is: [Guidelines for inadequately referenced answers](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/guidelines-for-inadequately-referenced-answers).

Comment: Linking to a meta post explaining the policy should be a good idea.