# Are people with the trusted users privilege allowed to vote to delete unreferenced answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, deletion, privileges

Diamond moderators regularly delete answers on the grounds that they are unreferenced. (Ironically enough, I can find a FAQ stating that [answers must be referenced](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/faq-must-all-answers-be-referenced), but couldn't find any post saying that unreferenced answers get deleted) However, in the help section for [trusted users](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), it says:

> Deleting answers
>
> When should I vote to delete an answer?
>
> You may vote to delete answers in the following cases:
>
> - The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
> - The answer doesn't attempt to answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether.

Does this mean that trusted users shouldn't delete answers on the grounds that they are unreferenced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to 20k, Andrew!

Here's the reference you are looking for: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers

> ## Why and how are some answers deleted?
>
> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are:

[...]

> - lacking factual references from reputable sources

Regarding your original question, the link answers positively:

> Answers can also be deleted by the community. Moderators can delete any answer, and trusted community members can vote to delete answers scoring -1 or lower (3 votes will result in deletion).

---

This explains why the FAQ is different: [The deletion FAQ item should reflect site policy](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/the-deletion-faq-item-should-reflect-site-policy)

> This is part of the network-wide FAQ, we can't change that part of the FAQ for just this site

---

Finally, this is the general reference for moderating inadequately referenced answers. I think it should apply to all users.  [Guidelines for Inadequately Referenced Answers](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/guidelines-for-inadequately-referenced-answers)

Comment: Thanks for the congratulations! I ought to improve the tagging of https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/the-deletion-faq-item-should-reflect-site-policy , and someone with even more privileges than me should improve the tagging of https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/guidelines-for-inadequately-referenced-answers

Comment: In the question, it says "Diamond moderators regularly delete answers on the grounds that they are unreferenced." I just want to reinforce the link to the Guidelines above. I don't delete answers merely because they are unreferenced. I annotate them, comment on them (when my device has a usable keyboard!) and try to remember to clean them up >1 week later. The clean-up schedule isn't rigorous at all; I did a session of cleaning up a few dozen years-old examples recently, but didn't touch any less than 6 months old.